# Why are only some of my attributes shown in the response xml of jaxws?

Tags: java, xml, jax-ws

I created a jaxws webservice, but it returns only some of the attributes of my objects in the response xml.

E.g.

```
public class MyObject {
   private String attribute1;
   private String attribute2;

   //getter and setter
}
```

But the returned XML only contains

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:mynamespaceResponse xmlns:ns2="mynamespace">
         <myObject>
            <attribute1>stringcontent</attribute1>
         </myObject>
             ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes which are null are not shown in the XML. 
In the example, attribute 2 is null, and therefore it's not shown.